# How to access member of another class from a class?

Tags: c#

I would like to access members of `Example2` in `example1`? would like to assign values for another class

```
    public class Example1
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Example2 obj;
    }

 public class RiskState
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

Can any one help me with this please? I would like to assign `obj.FirstName =""` some value. I am creating object for `Example1` and from there I would like to assign value for `Example2` object as well.

Comment: `var e = new Example1(); e.FirstName="XX"; e.obj = new RiskState(); e.obj.Number = 2;`

Comment: The same way you access information in the same class. With the dot notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `obj` variable is `public`, so any code with a reference to an instance of `Example1` can access it.

For example:

```
var someExample = new Example1();
someExample.obj = new Example2();             // you can access the property
someExample.obj.SomeProperty = "some value";  // you can access the property's property
                                              // etc.
```

Of course, the property you're accessing on `Example2` must also be `public`.

---

> access members of `Example2` in `example1`

The same notation applies.  Of course, when you're within the context of an instance of `Example1`, you automatically have a reference to that instance.  For exmaple:

```
// in a method on Example1
this.obj = new Example2();             // access the property
this.obj.SomeProperty = "some value";  // access the property's property
```

Comment: Thank you. how to access if its Public List<Example2> obj1> Appreciate your help

Comment: @CuriousDev: The same way.  Except of course that the type of the property is different.  What happens when you *try*?